# What are the possibilities of values in fragment's onAttach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-context

As we all know, the `onAttach(Activity)` method was deprecated and `onAttach(Context)` is now supposed to be used.

My question is - Won't the context of onAttach always be Activity? What else can a fragment be attached to if not Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L1444) we can see that the parameter doesn't do anything. If you watch deeper to [FragmentHostCallback](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentHostCallback.java) you can see that context and activity can be different for fragment. (I don't understand why and how but the implementation shows such possibility). And the comment above the [FragmentHostCallback](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentHostCallback.java#L33) tell us that "Fragments may be hosted by any object".

Comment: Do you have an example for a different context to which a fragment can be attached to?